# Where can I find the source code of tensorflow_lite_gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

The blog [TensorFlow Lite Now Faster with Mobile GPUs](https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-now-faster-with-mobile-gpus-developer-preview-e15797e6dee7) introduce the GPU feature of tensorflow-lite and I have tried the demo followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu) tutorial, but I can not find the source code about GPU, so, is it still not open source?

Comment: Same issue. I noticed that the file “tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/metal_delegate.h”, which is included if TFLITE_USE_GPU_DELEGATE == 1 is absent in the repository. I concluded that the demo from the tutorial itself loads the finished build with gpu function implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A full open-source release is planned in later 2019, incorporating the feedback we collect from your experiences."
So, expect the code to be added later this year.

Comment: yep, I found this sentence later in the blog, thanks reply~